# Correct tf frames setting in ndt_matching

Tags: ros, robotics

ndt_matching succeeded in autoware, but the vehicle model cannot be set correctly.

1. How do I set the correct angle for the vehicle model?
2. What does the frame "mobility" mean?

tf.launch

```
<node pkg="tf"  type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_to_map" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /world /map 10" />
<node pkg="tf"  type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_points_map" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /points_map 10" />
<node pkg="tf"  type="static_transform_publisher" name="velodyne_to_lidar_top" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /velodyne /lidar_top 10" />
```

[Image for RViz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s77bf.png)

[Image for TF Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crr17.png)

Comment: Hi! I see your static transforms and Rviz/TF tree - your TF tree and transforms looks fine to me. What do you mean by "Correct angle for vehicle model"? Is that the pose of the vehicle (base_link) with respect to map? That transform is likely being published by either the simulator (gazebo) or the localization (EKF/UKF) node. Also, I don't see a frame "mobility"... no clue what that is; please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Correct, the vehicle model needs to face the upper right (first image).
I changed the yaw angle of Baselinke to localizer on Setup tab, but the angle of point_raw itself was also changed and ndt_matching failed.
How can I change the angle of only the vehicle_model?

Comment: I'm still not positive what you're asking for, since I'm unfamiliar with this "ndt_matching" or "autoware", but usually you change the angle of the vehicle model by sending an update to the localization node (ekf?) that publishes the transform from base_link to map. Sending a [service from the commandline](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html) should do the trick (if that's what you're asking for).

Comment: As you said, the map to base_link setting was wrong.
Thanks for the support!

Comment: Cool... Would you like to post an answer that describes what you did to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings in the TF file were correct.
To change the angle of the vehicle model, I made the following settings.

1. Change the yaw setting of `Baselink to Localizer` in the `Setup` tab (in the direction you want the vehicle model to point).
2. Set the yaw setting of `ndt_matching` to offset it.(if baselink angle(1) is -1.55, here it is +1.55)

I wrote an article about these issues, Thank you JWCS!

https://medium.com/yodayoda/localization-with-autoware-3e745f1dfe5d